# while running robotium error messge has been displayed "does not have a signature matching the target com.android.calculator2"

Tags: robotium

Here is my code

```
package com.test.android.calculator2;

import android.app.Activity;

import com.robotium.solo.Solo;

import android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2;

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")

public class TestApk extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 {

    private static final String TARGET_PACKAGE_ID="com.android.calculator2";
    private static final String
    LAUNCHER_ACTIVITY_FULL_CLASSNAME="com.android.calculator2.Calculator";

    private static Class <?> launcherActivityClass;
    static {
        try {
            Activity act = new Activity();
            launcherActivityClass = Class.forName(LAUNCHER_ACTIVITY_FULL_CLASSNAME);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
    // @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")

    public TestApk()throws ClassNotFoundException {
        super(TARGET_PACKAGE_ID,launcherActivityClass);
    }
    private Solo solo;
    @Override
    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        solo = new Solo(getInstrumentation());
    }
    public void testCanOpenSettings() {
        solo.getActivityMonitor();
        getActivity();

        solo.sendKey(Solo.DOWN);
        solo.goBack();
    }

    @Override
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        try {
            solo.finalize();
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        getActivity().finish();
        super.tearDown();
    }
}
```

Manifest file like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    package="com.test.android.calculator2"

    android:versionCode="1"

    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="19" />

    <instrumentation

        android:name="android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner"
        android:targetPackage="com.android.calculator2" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <uses-library android:name="android.test.runner" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your defined target package `com.android.calculator2` could not be found.

I see that the class you posted is located in the package `com.test.android.calculator2`

You either have to create a new package  `com.android.calculator2` or set your target package to a existing package (e.g. `com.test.android.calculator2`).

Comment: But target package and test package should not be same right.?and i am testing inbuilt calculator package

Comment: That certainly makes sense. In that case you have to create the package `com.android.calculator2`beforehand, otherwise your program won't be able to find it.